# Javascript Object Creating in Java

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, object

Sorry if I named this bad, but I was just wondering how I do something like -

```
var Me = {Name: "Bob", Age: 20};
```

But instead of in Javascript, I want to do it in JAVA.

Answer (score 2):

The code you provided shows how to create objects in Javascript. In order to do the same in Java, you would need to create a class that contains both Name and Age as attributes. Here's a resource with more info(keep an eye on the section **Classes in Java**): http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm

Comment: This is what I wanted, sorry If i explained what I wanted poorly. I just wanted to be able to do the same effect in JAva.

Comment: It made perfect sense to me. Good luck! :D